Why was I not allowed to publish my book on Google Play Books?
Can you explain why I was not allowed to publish my book on Google Play Books? I am from Ukraine, but I indicated Ireland as the country for my bank account. I also have an account with Payoneer. Could this be a factor, or are there other specific requirements or policies that I may not have met for publishing my book?

I would recommend contacting Google to find out more, or at the very least a Google Play Books forum where more knowledgeable users might hang out.

I posted on the Google Play Books support forum, but my question wasn't posted and I didn't get any responses. I can go to my question, but no one else can see it, so I can't provide a link.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to ebooks but to Google Books.

Google Books is also an e-book. Plus, there is a related tag on this forum - google-play-books
